# Web scraping information from different websites

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Im using a gem called [MetaInspector](https://github.com/jaimeiniesta/metainspector) to scrape data from different websites. Im building a site where i can collect data from different sites but am having trouble setting up. I have a model called site with a title and a url both strings. When i create a new "site" the name will come out as example.com/"sitename" and in there i would like to have the data just from that site. I kinda have an idea to this by adding page = MetaInspector.new to the new method but cant see how i can set a url in there.
I can show my controller and other info if needed.

Controller

```
  class Admin::SitesController < Admin::ApplicationController
   def index
     @sites = Site.all
   end

   def show
     @site = Site.friendly.find(params[:id])
   end

   def edit
     @site = Site.friendly.find(params[:id])
   end

   def update
     @site = Site.friendly.find(params[:id])
     if @site.update(site_params)
       redirect_to admin_path
     else
       render :edit
     end
   end

   def destroy
     @site = Site.friendly.find(params[:id])
     @site.destroy
     if @site.destroy
       redirect_to admin_path
     end
    end

    def new
      @site = Site.new
    end

    def create
       @site = Site.new(site_params)
       if @site.save
          redirect_to admin_path
       else
          render :new
       end
     end

    private
      def site_params
        params.require(:site).permit(:title, :url)
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correct you want to show the metainfo for a `Site` you have added. You could put that code in the `show` action of the controller:

```
def show
  @site = Site.friendly.find(params[:id])
  @page = MetaInspector.new(@site.url)
end
```

And update the `show.html.erb` template to display info about `@page`, ie:

```
<%= @page.title %>
```